# Node JS not sending file with res.sendFile()

Tags: node.js

[image]

My file structure is shown above, but I am unable to find the file with error: Undefined is not a function.

The app path is set, which I can get via a console.log:
/Users/myname/Desktop/myproject/client

If I navigate to localhost:3000 for example, the page is rendered correctly. I can then click to navigate to localhost:3000/login and everything is still all good. But if I go directly to localhost:3000/login, i.e. the index page is never loaded, then this route: '/*' is hit and the undefined error occurs. No HTML is loaded.

I set the app path like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));
    app.set('appPath', path.join(__dirname, '/client'));
```

I am using Express:
"~4.0.0"

Comment: Let me guess -- you're hosting this on Parse? If not, where are you hosting it?

Comment: What does `path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html')` output?

Comment: /Users/myname/Desktop/myproject/client

Comment: @keithmo im just trying to run it locally

Comment: @JoshC. it outputs :/Users/myname/Desktop/myproject/client/index.html

Comment: @JoshC. as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the root for relative file path, this way:

```
app.set('base', __dirname);
```

and then:

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
```

Make sure not to include `/client` twice, so you don't get something like `.../client/client...` in your path.

Answer (score 0):

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile

`res.sendFile() is supported from Express v4.8.0 onwards`

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

Regards